# Rational approximation of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ for the diophantine $x^3 - 2y^3 = 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

In the book 'A Classical Approach to Modern Number Theory' by Ireland and Rosen,
the penultimate paragraph of Chapter 17(Diophantine Equations) mentions,

> Thus while $x^2 - 2y^2 = 1$ has infinitely many integral solutions, $x^3 -2y^3 = 1$ has only finitely many integral solutions.

I want to prove the latter fact.
The polynomial $t^3 -2$ has a root at $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

I think I need to show that
$$
\left| \sqrt[3]{2} - \frac{p}{q} \right| > \frac{c}{q^{3- \epsilon}}
$$
for some $c,  3 >  \epsilon > 0$ and apply the result proved in the previous paragraph which says

This is equivalent to showing that for some epsilon $|\sqrt[3]{2} - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^{3- \epsilon}}$ is satisfied by only finitely many rationals.

But I cannot prove this.

Comment: @coffeemath corrected now.

Comment: Some inequalities of the type you mention follow from the continued fraction expansion of the irrational approximated. [I don't know whether $\sqrt[3]{2}$ has a simple expansion.]

Comment: No, @coffeemath , the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt[3]2$ looks very random, no rhyme or reason to it.

Comment: Replace $y$ by $-y$  to arrive at $x^3 + 2 y^3 = 1.$  Theorem 5 on page 220 of Mordell, Diophantine Equations, says there is at most one integr solution with $xy \neq 0$ The proof continues to page 225.

Comment: What are sample integer solutions for the first equation? Why do you say they are infinite?

Comment: @NoChance The first equation $x^2-2y^2=1$ is called a *Pell equation*. It has infinitely many integers solutions, see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481146/all-solutions-of-a-pells-equation-x2-2y2-1).